# Search for a table in MySQL Database via Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm writing down a script that creates a table into a database using `mysql.connector` in **python**

I've created the function

```
def create_table(connection):
    try:
        tb = 'D' + str(datetime.date.today())
        table_name = tb[:5] + tb[6:8] + tb[9:]

        if not find_table(connection, table_name):

            mySql_Create_Table_Query = """CREATE TABLE """ + table_name + """ (
                                        Id int(11) NOT NULL,
                                        Name varchar(3) NOT NULL,
                                        Date_check int(32) NOT NULL,
                                        Price float NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (Id)) """

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(mySql_Create_Table_Query)
            print("Table created successfully ")
            cursor.reset()

        else:
            return

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to create table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
        if not connection.is_connected():
            print("You're not connected to a database")
```

that receives as input the `connection` object (which in my case is returned by another function called `connect()` ) and then, given the current date it generates the table name and then the actual table.

Everything works fine besides the `if not find_table(connection, table_name)`

THe function `find_table(connection, table _ame)` receives as input the connection object and the table name as string and performs a research as below:

```
def find_table(connection, table_name):
    try:

        mySql_Find_Table_Query = """SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM information_schema.tables 
                                    WHERE table_schema = 'thegrkle_trading' 
                                    AND table_name = '""" + table_name + """'; """

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(mySql_Find_Table_Query)
        print(result)

        if str(result) == 'None':
            print("The table does not exist ")
            cursor.reset()
            return False
        else:
            print("The table already exist ")
            cursor.reset()
            return True

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to find table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
        if not connection.is_connected():
            print("You're not connected to a database")
```

For some reason, even with the table existing in my database, the find_table function returns `False`.

I've tried to run the SQL query `mySql_Find_Table_Query` directly into the database via PHPMyAdmin and it works fine. I can't understand because my function always returns that the table doesn't exist

Comment: Count(*) will return a number in all cases. It will be 0, if no table was found. Also, it would be a lot simpler to write create tabke if not exists ...

Comment: @Shadow the issue was `execute()` always return `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `cursor.execute(mySql_Find_Table_Query)` always returns `None` if the query is executed correctly.

The solution was to use the `fetchone()` and checking the value of the tuple with

```
cursor.execute(mySql_Find_Table_Query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result[0] == 0:
            print("The table does not exist ")
            cursor.reset()
            return False
        else:
            print("The table already exist ")
            cursor.reset()
            return True
```